# What is the biggest positive integer within 100 that can be/can not be written as the differences between two positive primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the biggest positive integer within 100 that can be/can not be written as the differences between two positive primes?

Can someone answer the cannot part?

There are *two* parts in the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differences of primes are generally even (except when $2$ is involved).

$99$ can be written as $101 - 2$. Therefore a lower bound for the largest number which cannot be written as a difference of primes is $97$. It remains to check that $100$ and $98$ actually can be written as a difference of primes. Some simple trial and error will reveal that
$$101 - 3 = 98$$
$$103 - 3 = 100$$

Comment: What about the can not be part?

Comment: That's where $97$ comes in.

Comment: Eu Yu - Thanks you very much.